# Remove row names from a list of dataframes?

Tags: r, dataframe, quantmod

My code:

```
library(quantmod)
library(tseries)
library(ggplot2)
companies = c("IOC.BO", "BPCL.BO", "ONGC.BO", "HINDPETRO.BO", "GAIL.BO")
stocks = list()
for(i in 1:5){
 stocks[[i]] = getSymbols(companies[i], auto.assign = FALSE)
}
```

`stocks` is a list of dataframes. Now I'm trying to bind the all $adjusted columns all the dataframes stored in `stock` but to do that I need to remove the rownames (someone please tell me if there's a better method to do this):

```
for(i in 1:5)
 rownames(stocks[[i]])<- NULL
```

but the resulting dataframes still have their row names, could someone please tell me where I'm going wrong?

P.S. Further my end goal is to have a dataframe with only the adjusted columns of the dataframes in the list `stocks` for which I did this:

```
adjusted=data.frame()
for(i in 1:5)
  coln=stocks[[1]][,6]
  adjusted=cbind(ajusted,coln)
adjusted
```

but this returns adjusted as a list.

Comment: Your last loop does not depend on the loop control variable `i`, it just repeats the same 2 statements 5 times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Row names

Regarding row names after running the code in the question

```
rownames(stocks[[1]])
## NULL
```

so it is not true that stocks have row names afterwards.

### Adjusted series

To create a time series of adjusted values use `Ad` as shown below.

```
Adjusted <- do.call("merge", lapply(stocks, Ad))
```

### Putting it all together

Note that we don't really need the entire row names processing and the following is sufficient.  The second last line is optional as its only purpose is to make the column names nicer and the last line converts the xts object `Adjusted` to a data frame and may not be needed either since you may find working with an xts object more convenient than using data frames.

```
library(quantmod)
library(ggplot2)

stocks <- lapply(companies, getSymbols, auto.assign = FALSE)
Adjusted <- do.call("merge", lapply(stocks, Ad))
names(Adjusted) <- sub(".BO.Adjusted", "", names(Adjusted))
adjustedDF <- fortify(Adjusted)
```